# unexcepted thymeleaf symbols and unexcepted values

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, thymeleaf

> I want ro concate some things in thymeleaf but  concate symbol throws
> unexcepted '+' error, I define ctotal in my common.kt class and want
> to use the reference of the ctotal in cart.html but ctotal shows under
> redline error I donot know which type of error it
> cart.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:replace="fragments/head.html">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<nav th:replace="/fragments/nav :: nav-front"></nav>

<div class="container-fluid mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div th:replace="/fragments/categories"></div>
        <div class="col"></div>
        <div class="col-7">
            <div class="overlay text-center d-none">
                <h4 class="display-4">You are being redirected to paypal...</h4>
                <img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="">
            </div>
            <h2 class="display-4">Cart Overview</h2>
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Image</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                </tr>
                <tr th:each="el: ${cart}">
                    <td th:text="${el.value.name}"></td>
                    <td>
                        <img style="width: 100px;" th:src="@{'/media/' + ${el.value.image}}" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span th:text="${el.value.quantity}"></span>
                        <a th:href="@{'/cart/add/'+${el.value.id}} + '?cartPage=true'"
                           class="btn btn-success btn-sm">+</a>
                        <a th:href="@{'/cart/subtract/'+${el.value.id}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">-</a>
                        <a th:href="@{'/cart/remove/'+${el.value.id}}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">remove</a>
                    </td>
                    <td th:text="'$' + ${el.value.price}"></td>
                    <td th:with="formattedTotal=${el.value.price} * ${el.value.quantity}" th:text="'$' + ${#numbers.formatDecimal(formattedTotal, 0, 'COMMA', 2, 'POINT')}"
                    >
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-right" colspan="4"><b>Grand Total:</b></td>
                    <td colspan="1" th:text="'$' + ${#numbers.formatDecimal(ctotal, 0, 'COMMA', 2, 'POINT')}"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="/cart/clear" class="btn btn-danger">Clear Cart</a>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="4" class="text-right">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success checkout">Checkout</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<form id="paypalform" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="zennil1305014666@gmail.com">

    <th:block th:each="el, iter : ${cart}">
        <input type="hidden" th:name="'item_name_'+${iter.count}" th:value="${el.value.name}">
        <input type="hidden" th:name="'amount_'+${iter.count}" th:value="${el.value.price}">
        <input type="hidden" th:name="'quantity_'+${iter.count}" th:value="${el.value.quantity}">
    </th:block>

    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>

<div th:replace="/fragments/footer"></div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("a.checkout").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("div.overlay").removeClass("d-none");
            $.get("/cart/clear", {}, function () {});
            $("form#paypalform").submit();
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

> i got error exact line 33 on the '+' symbol

```
<a th:href="@{'/cart/add/'+${el.value.id}} + '?cartPage=true'"
                           class="btn btn-success btn-sm">+</a>
```

> And got red underlined error below  line

```
<td colspan="1" th:text="'$' + ${#numbers.formatDecimal(ctotal, 0, 'COMMA', 2, 'POINT')}"></td>
```

> at ctotal i got redline error .ctotal i defined in my common class
> common.kt

```
package com.nilmani.cmsshopingcart

import com.nilmani.cmsshopingcart.model.Cart
import com.nilmani.cmsshopingcart.model.Category
import com.nilmani.cmsshopingcart.model.Page
import com.nilmani.cmsshopingcart.repository.CategoryRepository
import com.nilmani.cmsshopingcart.repository.PageRepository
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.ui.Model
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute
import java.security.Principal
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession

@ControllerAdvice
class Common {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var pageRepo: PageRepository
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var categoryRepo: CategoryRepository

    @ModelAttribute
    fun sharedData(model: Model, session: HttpSession, principal: Principal?) {
        if (principal != null) {
            model.addAttribute("principal", principal.name)
        }
        val pages: List<Page> = pageRepo.findAllByOrderBySortingAsc()
        val categories: List<Category> = categoryRepo.findAllByOrderBySortingAsc()
        var cartActive = false
        if (session.getAttribute("cart") != null) {
            val cart: HashMap<Int, Cart> = session.getAttribute("cart") as HashMap<Int, Cart>
            var size = 0
            var total = 0.0
            for (value in cart.values) {
                size += value.quantity
                total += value.quantity * value.price.toDouble()
            }
            model.addAttribute("csize", size)
            model.addAttribute("ctotal", total)
            cartActive = true
        }
        model.addAttribute("cpages", pages)
        model.addAttribute("ccategories", categories)
        model.addAttribute("cartActive", cartActive)
    }

}
```

Comment: Regarding the `+` syntax error, it looks like you are mixing two different types of syntax: (1) link urls and (2) string concatenation. Look at the link URL building examples in the [official documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#link-urls). They do not use (or need to use) concatenation. Instead, look at how the `@{ ... }` syntax uses placeholders - and how you place your variables into those placeholders.

Comment: You want to use standard URL syntax `<a th:href="@{/order/details(id=3,action='show_all')}">`. From: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html